# Gradle: Exclude a file from inside a dependency when publishing a jar

Tags: gradle

I'm using `maven-publish` with gradle to publish a library jar. That library depends on `libtensorflow_jni.jar`, which contains several large binaries inside it. In order to reduce the size of the library below a 3rd party limit I'm running into, I would like to exclude the (unneeded) Windows dll binary file from inside the libtensorflow_jni jar when building my overall package.

Is there any reasonable way to exclude a specific file from inside a dependency when publishing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a clean way to do this so I used a hacky shell script:

```sh
set -ex

# remove unneeded large binaries from the deployed zip file to avoid going over Lambda limits

cd build/distributions/
unzip -o app.zip
rm app.zip
zip -d lib/libtensorflow_jni-*.jar org/tensorflow/native/windows-x86_64/tensorflow_jni.dll
zip -d lib/libtensorflow_jni-*.jar org/tensorflow/native/darwin-x86_64/libtensorflow_jni.dylib
zip -r app.zip .
```

And called this script in `build.gradle` from a task as follows:

```
task shrinkAppJar(type: Exec) {
    commandLine './shrink-jar.sh'
}

build.dependsOn buildZip, shrinkAppJar
```